# How to set width of image inside button in Xamarin.Forms xaml?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know if it is possible to set the width and height of the image inside this button:

```
<Button Image="ic_music_white.png" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="White" HeightRequest="56"  BackgroundColor="PowderBlue" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="Button_Clicked">
</Button>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 10):

You could always create an Image control and add a tap gesture recognizer to it. That way you have more control over the image size and placement.

**XAML**

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="ic_music_white.png" HeightRequest="56"  BackgroundColor="PowderBlue" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
TapGestureRecognizer tapEvent = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapEvent.Tapped += Button_Clicked;
myImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapEvent);
```

Comment: You could, but then you lose the visual states of the button: Pressed, Focused, PointerOver, Disabled would all look the same. With `ImageButton` you get to keep these. See Ricardo's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73218728/6151543

Answer (score 6):

On an iOS project, padding can adjust the size of the image within the button. If you have a width of 50, padding 10, the resulting image width will be 30.

Comment: Padding and margins with fixed number of pixels can lead to layout issues when the resolution changes

Answer (score 5):

Use `<ImageButton Source"yourImage" Padding=10 Aspect="AspectFit"/>`

You can controle the image size with the **padding** ;)

Answer (score 3):

No,you can't manage the height/width of image inside `button` .
The better option would be to create a stacklayout and then put text and image inside it.
The way i did it:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="60">

                <Label Text="Review task" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Image Source="nextarrow_white.png" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="32" Margin="20,4,0,0"/>

        </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible from the Xamarin.Forms project but you can create custom renderers which will allow you to modify the properties of the native control.

In the case of the iOS you will be changing the [ImageEdgeInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624034-imageedgeinsets).

For Android you might want to take a look at the [Button renderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ButtonRenderer.cs) so you can get any ideas.

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to place buttons inside a screen without adding text or other content, you could place your buttons inside a Grid layout as following

```js
<Grid RowDefinitions="auto"
              ColumnDefinitions="auto"
              Margin="40 40 40 40">
              
              <ImageButton Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Source="Resources/Images/installations.png"
                         HorizontalOptions="Center"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"/>
          </Grid>
```

There, you apply a margin to the grid layout, this case images will automatically adjust their sizes to fit the available space.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use scale to change the size of the content.
And padding to add the border around the image.

Example

```cs
  <Button 
    Image="ic_music_white.png" 
    BorderWidth="1"  
    BorderColor="White" 
    HeightRequest="56"  
    BackgroundColor="PowderBlue" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    Clicked="Button_Clicked"
    Scale = "0.7",
    Padding = "10"
    >
  </Button>
```

Answer (score -5):

You have missed to add WidthRequest. Can you add WidthRequest like below

```
<Button Image="ic_music_white.png" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="White" HeightRequest="56" WidthRequest="56"  BackgroundColor="PowderBlue" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="Button_Clicked">
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Venky, but if I put WidthRequest in <Button> modify the Width of the Button, not the width of the image inside the button