# MAUI .NET 8 Images doesn't fit in button anymore

Tags: c#, button, maui, .net-8.0

I'm creating a multiplatform MAUI application for Windows and Mac platforms. I've updated project to .NET 8 recently and I'm having some issues with buttons now. There is no property for controlling image size in buttons. In .NET 7, I was able to control images size by changing the padding values. But this is not working anymore.

Buttons were looking like this before update;

[image: before update]

After updated to .NET 8, all buttons with images looks like this now;

[image: after update]

This is the `XAML` code I'm using currently;

```
<Button Text="User" ImageSource="dotnet_bot.png" Padding="0,15,83,5" HeightRequest="35" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="225"/>
```

**Extra Info**

- I tried creating custom control, but we can't define clicked or pressed event other than button controls. So, this solution also doesn't work.
- I've researched for other solutions, but they are all answered before .NET 8. Here are some questions I've looked; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465490/dotnet-maui-button-control-the-imagesource-size), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746135/how-to-resize-image-inside-button-in-net-maui), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453342/how-to-set-width-of-image-inside-button-in-xamarin-forms-xaml), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470529/net-maui-image-wrong-size), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922217/in-maui-how-to-adjust-an-image-of-a-button-to-the-size-of-the-button) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73356024/how-to-create-custom-control-in-maui-with-an-event-handler) questions.
- Also, `ContentLayout` property is not helpful. It just adjusts spacing between text and image.
- Smaller images may be a solution but changing all of the assets for this problem is not a good approach. We need these assets in different sizes.

Is there any solution for this issue? Any idea is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you choose to go the "custom control" strategy, the way to _define clicked or pressed event_ is with gesture recognizers. Is that something you considered at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75753300/5438626 you say you looked at this thread already. What about this specific answer? It looks right to me...

Comment: Thanks for your comment IV, I've tried `GestureRecognizers` too. If I use `GestureRecognizers` while creating my control in a page, it does not recognize any kind of input. If I define them inside of my custom control (for Border for example) I can't bind, `Tapped` event for different buttons. So, I used `ICommand` interface instead. These buttons are mostly for opening new windows or pages, the defined ICommand interface is in viewmodel of course and our viewmodel doesn't know view.  It wouldn't be good if it knew. Not a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment indicates that you had some problems with the gesture recognizer with a custom control. I wanted to offer an alternative to using a tap gesture recognizer the way it's shown in the answer that I linked. Putting an invisible `Button` over a visual layout below it in the z-order gives you lots of control over layout, and gives you the benefit of having both `Clicked` and `Pressed` events. My personal spin would be to still (like the other answer) use `Frame` as the content view so that the "button" corners can still have the rounded appearance.

[image: demo of clicked response]

In the xaml below, the internal controls will bind to both standard properties of `Frame` (e.g. the button will track `Frame.CornerRadius`) and we can also introduce custom bindable properties in the code behind such as `ImageMargin` and `ImageSource` that a frame doesn't ordinarily expose.

---

**ButtonEx**

This code (in two parts) will yield a custom extended `<controls:ButtonEx>` that can (for example) be swapped out for `<Button>`  in the MAUI default `MainPage`, features `Clicked` and `Pressed` events, and shows how exposing custom bindable properties (like `ImageMargin`) can help "dial in" the behavior you want.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Frame 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:net_8_image_buttons.Controls"
    x:Class="net_8_image_buttons.Controls.ButtonEx"
    Padding="0"
    CornerRadius="10">
    <Grid
        ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <!--Pull properties down from the wrapper for individual controls-->
        <Image 
            WidthRequest="50"
            Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:ButtonEx}}}"
            Margin="{Binding Path=ImageMargin, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:ButtonEx}}}"
            InputTransparent="True"/>   
        <Label         
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Text="{Binding Path=Text, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:ButtonEx}}}"         
            TextColor="{Binding Path=TextColor, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:ButtonEx}}}"        
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            InputTransparent="True"/>
        <Button         
            x:Name="GestureRecognizerEx"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            CornerRadius="{Binding Path=CornerRadius, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:ButtonEx}}}"
            BorderColor="{Binding Path=BorderColor, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:ButtonEx}}}"
            BorderWidth="{Binding Path=BorderWidth, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:ButtonEx}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

---

**Custom Bindable Properties**

You can make the `ButtonEx` behave more (or less) like  a `Button` depending on the custom properties you choose to expose.

```cs
public partial class ButtonEx : Frame
{
    public ButtonEx()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GestureRecognizerEx.Clicked += (sender, e) => Clicked?.Invoke(this, e);
        GestureRecognizerEx.Pressed += (sender, e) => Pressed?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(ButtonEx), default(string));

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ButtonEx), default(ImageSource)); 
    
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ButtonEx), default(Color));

    public Color TextColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(TextColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderWidthProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderWidth), typeof(double), typeof(ButtonEx), default(double));

    public double BorderWidth
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(BorderWidthProperty);
        set => SetValue(BorderWidthProperty, value);
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageMarginProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageMargin), typeof(Thickness), typeof(ButtonEx), default(Thickness));

    public Thickness ImageMargin
    {
        get => (Thickness)GetValue(ImageMarginProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageMarginProperty, value);
    }
    public event EventHandler? Clicked;
    public event EventHandler? Pressed;
}
```

---

**MAUI MainPage**

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout
    Padding="30,0"
    Spacing="25">
    <Image
        Source="dotnet_bot.png"
        HeightRequest="185"
        Aspect="AspectFit"
        SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

    <Label
        Text="Hello, World!"
        Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
        SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

    <Label
        Text="Welcome to &#10;.NET Multi-platform App UI"
        Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
        SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
        SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I" />

    <controls:ButtonEx
        x:Name="CounterBtn"
        SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        Text="Click me" 
        TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
        Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
        ImageSource="dotnet_bot.png"
        ImageMargin="10,0,0,0"
        BorderColor="Fuchsia"
        BorderWidth="1"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/net-8-image-buttons.git)

Comment: Thank you for your answer IV, it works perfectly! But I should point out something, when I clicked on the `Image` or `Label` button doesn't work. I guess it's because button is under them. When I clicked empty area, it works. So, I changed the position of the button to be at the top in custom control. I've edited your answer according to this. If I'm wrong, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Wow. I believe you, but I can't repro the behavior on either of my Android physical devices. But just confirming this - you're running a straight clone from my GitHub, right?

Comment: Yes I cloned your repo. I didn't test on android but in windows. Maybe this may be a Windows specific problem. I thought `InputTransparent` property should fix but even if it's value `true` or `false` doesn't change anything on windows for now.

Comment: Ah! Ok. The shocking thing to me is that you're getting .NET 8 to deploy on Windows Machine. I haven't been able to do that yet, although .NET 7 works just fine.  Truth is I really like your edit. I've been known to put transparent buttons over a segment button before so I could "reselect" a segment. It's a very good technique and if it brings Windows in line as a bonus then I'm for it!

Comment: Glad to hear that IV, I really appreciate your help. Thanks :)